# One-way updates of columns using EntityFramework

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0

EntityFramework 4.3.1.

What is the best way to have calculated properties which should be stored in db, but are not intended to be retrieved from db?
E.g.

```
    [Column("SOME_COLUMN")]
    public ulong SomeColumn
    {
        get { return /*calculate here*/; }
    }
```

I want the value to be persisted when I'm saving to db. But of course - not getting updated when I load from db. I can have an empty setter alongside... But it doesn't seem to work when the column is Key.

Can I have such a Key-column?

Now I'm getting this error:

**EntityFramework error: The value of a property that is part of an object's key does not match the corresponding property value stored in the ObjectContext. This can occur if properties that are part of the key return inconsistent or incorrect values or if DetectChanges is not called after changes are made to a property that is part of the key.**

Comment: What are you using the calculated properties for if they shouldn't be read from the database?  Also, can't you just add a calculated column to the database?

Comment: Calculated columns are used for further processing by other apps - my app doesn't require them. I can't add calculated column to database - not in charge of this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make the setter private:

```
[Column("SOME_COLUMN")]
public ulong SomeColumn { get; private set; }
```

Secondly, add a calculation method in the object (so it can access the private setter):

```
public void CaculateSomeColumn(){
    this.SomeColumn = /* some calculation */;
}
```

Thirdly, add a `SavingChanges` callback to the Repository context object (`MyEntities`).  This callback can be defined in the context constructor, and it should set the calculated field for items of your type (`MyPoco`) that were added or modified:

```
public MyEntities(){
    this.SavingChanges += (sender, eventArgs) => {
        ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
        if (context != null)
        {

            foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in
                context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified))
            {
                if (!entry.IsRelationship && (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(MyPoco)))
                {
                    var myObject = entry.Entity as MyPoco;
                    myObject.CalculateSomeColumn();
                }
            }
        }

    };
}
```